# PHP - passing values to mysqli_connect

Tags: php

I have a legacy project, where I have a file with a class that in its construct method makes a connection with a database.

```
public $mysqli;

public function __construct(){
    $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect( "192.168.10.10", "homestead", "secret", "myDatabase" );
}
```

For now, I would like to make this somewhat flexible and make a config file with an array of values that I would pass to `mysqli_connect` method.  Something like this:

Config file:

```
$mysqliConfig = [
  '192.168.10.10',
  'homestead',
  'secret',
  'myDatabase'
];
```

And then just require that in the other file and use it in the class constructor of that file:

```
require_once 'includes/config.php';

class Calculator{

    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect($mysqliConfig);
    }
```

But that is not working, how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the variables from the config file available to the class.

```
require_once 'includes/config.php';

class Calculator{

    private $mysqli;

    public function __construct($mysqliConfig){
        $this->mysqli = mysqli_connect($mysqliConfig);
    }

}

$cal = new Calculator($mysqliConfig);
```

As an aside, I would use an associative array for the config to make it more readable.

```
$mysqliConfig = [
  'host' => '192.168.10.10',
  'database' => 'homestead',
  'user' => 'secret',
  'password' => 'myDatabase'
];

// E.g. $mysqliConfig['host']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [...](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-145) token to unpack the config into the argument list:

```
$this->mysqli = mysqli_connect(...$mysqliConfig);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for associate arrays?

Answer (score 0):

What i do is to have a .ini file Advantage is that it returns as a key value association.

save your config details in the .ini file(path/to/config.ini)
In config.ini file,

```
database_name = mydatabase_name
password = my_password
host = host
system_root = system_root
other_details = other_details
```

Then on your calculator class, do

```
    <?php
    $currentConfig = parse_ini_file(path/to/config/config.ini);

    print_r($currentConfig); # prints the entire parsed .ini file

    print($currentConfig ['database_name ']); #prints "mydatabase_name"

?>
```